# Reduce indentation of nested functions in Python code generation

Tags: python

My goal is to generate functions dynamically and then save them in a file. For e.g, in my current attempt, On calling `create_file`

```
import io


def create_file():
    nested_func = make_nested_func()
    write_to_file([nested_func, a_root_func], '/tmp/code.py')


def a_root_func(x):
    pass


def make_nested_func():
    def a_nested_func(b, k):
        return b, k

    return a_nested_func


def write_to_file(code_list, path):
    import inspect
    code_str_list = [inspect.getsource(c) for c in code_list]
    with open(path, 'w') as ofh:
        for c in code_str_list:
            fh = io.StringIO(c)
            ofh.writelines(fh.readlines())
            ofh.write('\n')


create_file()
```

The output I want is('/tmp/code.py'):

```
def a_nested_func(b, k):
        return b, k

def a_root_func(x):
    pass
```

The output I get is('/tmp/code.py'):

```
    def a_nested_func(b, k):
        return b, k

def a_root_func(x):
    pass
```

`a_nested_func` is indented. How can I reduce the indentation? I can do `lstrip` etc. but I wonder if there is a better way.

Comment: Find the least-indented line (likely the first will suffice). Find the amount of indentation in it. Cut the same amount from all lines before writing them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`textwrap.dedent()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent) to remove the common leading whitespace:

```
import inspect
from textwrap import dedent

def write_to_file(code_list, path):
    code_str_list = [inspect.getsource(c) for c in code_list]
    with open(path, 'w') as ofh:
        for c in code_str_list:
            dedented = dedent(c)
            ofh.write(dedented + '\n')
```

Note that there is no need for a `StringIO(string).readlines()` dance here.

Answer (score 3):

There's a function in built-in module, [`textwrap.dedent`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent).

```
import textwrap
s = """
   abc
     def
"""
s2 = """
abc
  def
"""
assert textwrap.dedent(s) == s2
```

Comment: Thanks, wish I could check your answer too!